# Can I get rid of async if my function doesn't have anything do with the awaited result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can I replace following function

```
public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(int id)
{
   return await _dbContext.Users.SingleAsync(id);
}
```

with:

```
public Task<User> GetUserAsync(int id)
{
   return _dbContext.Users.SingleAsync(id);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Both of them work fine

Comment: the question is - do you want to block until SingleAsync completes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a plausible assumption here: `_dbContext.Users.SingleAsync(id);` returns a `Task<User>`.

It's bad style to use `async` when you can just call a single function that returns a `Task` of the right type. It will handle the `async` for you. Your code size will be smaller, and your generated code size will be much smaller.

Controversial opinion: If there's a single `async` in the middle it should be replaced with `Task.ContinueWith()`.